# Odoo, compute sum field in a shared model

Tags: odoo-15

I have three class (Delivery, Order, DeliveryLine). both Delivery and Order has One2many field for DeliveryLine.

The issue now is **compute total delivery amount**

When I try to add multi different order records in Delivery model, the correct result is the total_delivery_amount in Order model will sum the amount from delivery_line_ids based on order_id. But the reality is it sum all the amount of delivery_line_ids. I don't know where is the tricky from.

```
class DeliveryLine(models.Model):
    _name = "delivery.line"

    delivery_id = fields.Many2one('delivery')
    order_id = fields.Many2one('order')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product')
    delivery_amount = fields.Integer()
```

```
class Delivery(models.Model):
    _name = "delivery"

    delivery_line_ids = fields.One2many('delivery.line','delivery_id')
```

```
class Order(models.Model):
    _name = "order"

    delivery_line_ids = fields.One2many('delivery.line','order_id')
    total_delivery_amount =fields.Integer(compute='_compute_total_amount',store=True)

   @api.depends("delivery_line_ids.delivery_amount")
    def _compute_total_amount(self):
        if self.delivery_line_ids:
            self.delivered_amount = sum(self.delivery_line_ids.mapped("delivery_amount"))
        else:
            self.delivered_amount = 0
```